# How to use Map type in Dynamodb in order to import to visualizer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I having the next DynamoDB table sample in AWS:

```
{
  "userId": {
    "S": "1"
  },
  "filter": {
    "M": {
      "asset": {
        "S": "test1"
      },
      "subFilter": {
        "M": {
          "documents": {
            "S": "test3"
          }
        }
      },
      "trash": {
        "S": "test2"
      }
    }
  },
  "lastName": {
    "S": "tabares"
  }
}
```

I wonder what is the correct way to tanslate to json file in order to import in NoSQL workbench, I am not sure what is the correct nesting of the map (objects) with the attributes, I am having the Music table sample but is using string seems more easy than handle map type:

```
{
  "ModelName": "Music Library Data Model",
  "ModelMetadata": {
    "Author": "Amazon Web Services, Inc.",
    "DateCreated": "Sep 05, 2019, 11:50 AM",
    "DateLastModified": "Jun 30, 2023, 02:19 AM",
    "Description": "This data model represents an Amazon DynamoDB schema for a music library application ",
    "Version": "3.0",
    "AWSService": "Amazon DynamoDB"
  },
  "DataModel": [
    {
      "TableName": "Songs",
      "KeyAttributes": {
        "PartitionKey": {
          "AttributeName": "Id",
          "AttributeType": "S"
        },
        "SortKey": {
          "AttributeName": "Metadata",
          "AttributeType": "S"
        }
      },
      "NonKeyAttributes": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "DownloadMonth",
          "AttributeType": "S"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "TotalDownloadsInMonth",
          "AttributeType": "S"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "Title",
          "AttributeType": "S"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "Artist",
          "AttributeType": "S"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "TotalDownloads",
          "AttributeType": "S"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "DownloadTimestamp",
          "AttributeType": "S"
        }
      ],
      "TableFacets": [
        {
          "FacetName": "SongDetails",
          "KeyAttributeAlias": {
            "PartitionKeyAlias": "SongId",
            "SortKeyAlias": "Metadata"
          },
          "NonKeyAttributes": [
            "Title",
            "Artist",
            "TotalDownloads"
          ],
          "TableData": [
            {
              "Id": {
                "S": "1"
              },
              "Metadata": {
                "S": "Details"
              },
              "Title": {
                "S": "Wild Love"
              },
              "Artist": {
                "S": "Argyboots"
              },
              "TotalDownloads": {
                "S": "3"
              }
            },
            {
              "Id": {
                "S": "2"
              },
              "Metadata": {
                "S": "Details"
              },
              "Title": {
                "S": "Example Song Title"
              },
              "Artist": {
                "S": "Jorge Souza"
              },
              "TotalDownloads": {
                "S": "4"
              }
            }
          ],
          "DataAccess": {
            "MySql": {}
          }
        },
        {
          "FacetName": "Downloads",
          "KeyAttributeAlias": {
            "PartitionKeyAlias": "SongId",
            "SortKeyAlias": "Metadata"
          },
          "NonKeyAttributes": [
            "DownloadTimestamp"
          ],
          "TableData": [
            {
              "Id": {
                "S": "1"
              },
              "Metadata": {
                "S": "Dld-9349823681"
              },
              "DownloadTimestamp": {
                "S": "2018-01-01T00:00:07"
              }
            },
            {
              "Id": {
                "S": "1"
              },
              "Metadata": {
                "S": "Dld-9349823682"
              },
              "DownloadTimestamp": {
                "S": "2018-01-01T00:01:08"
              }
            },
            {
              "Id": {
                "S": "1"
              },
              "Metadata": {
                "S": "Dld-9349823683"
              },
              "DownloadTimestamp": {
                "S": "2018-01-01T00:20:10"
              }
            },
            {
              "Id": {
                "S": "2"
              },
              "Metadata": {
                "S": "Dld-9349823684"
              },
              "DownloadTimestamp": {
                "S": "2018-01-02T00:00:00"
              }
            },
            {
              "Id": {
                "S": "2"
              },
              "Metadata": {
                "S": "Dld-9349823685"
              },
              "DownloadTimestamp": {
                "S": "2018-01-03T00:00:02"
              }
            },
            {
              "Id": {
                "S": "2"
              },
              "Metadata": {
                "S": "Dld-9349836234"
              },
              "DownloadTimestamp": {
                "S": "2018-01-04T01:00:03"
              }
            },
            {
              "Id": {
                "S": "2"
              },
              "Metadata": {
                "S": "Dld-9349823686"
              },
              "DownloadTimestamp": {
                "S": "2018-01-05T01:10:03"
              }
            }
          ],
          "DataAccess": {
            "MySql": {}
          }
        }
      ],
      "LocalSecondaryIndexes": [],
      "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
        {
          "IndexName": "DownloadsByMonth",
          "KeyAttributes": {
            "PartitionKey": {
              "AttributeName": "DownloadMonth",
              "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            "SortKey": {
              "AttributeName": "TotalDownloadsInMonth",
              "AttributeType": "S"
            }
          },
          "Projection": {
            "ProjectionType": "ALL"
          }
        }
      ],
      "TableData": [
        {
          "Id": {
            "S": "1"
          },
          "Metadata": {
            "S": "Month-01-2018"
          },
          "DownloadMonth": {
            "S": "01-2018"
          },
          "TotalDownloadsInMonth": {
            "S": "3"
          }
        },
        {
          "Id": {
            "S": "2"
          },
          "Metadata": {
            "S": "Month-01-2018"
          },
          "DownloadMonth": {
            "S": "01-2018"
          },
          "TotalDownloadsInMonth": {
            "S": "4"
          }
        }
      ],
      "DataAccess": {
        "MySql": {}
      },
      "BillingMode": "PROVISIONED",
      "ProvisionedCapacitySettings": {
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
          "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
          "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
        },
        "AutoScalingRead": {
          "ScalableTargetRequest": {
            "MinCapacity": 1,
            "MaxCapacity": 10,
            "ServiceRole": "AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_DynamoDBTable"
          },
          "ScalingPolicyConfiguration": {
            "TargetValue": 70
          }
        },
        "AutoScalingWrite": {
          "ScalableTargetRequest": {
            "MinCapacity": 1,
            "MaxCapacity": 10,
            "ServiceRole": "AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_DynamoDBTable"
          },
          "ScalingPolicyConfiguration": {
            "TargetValue": 70
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```